# Right usage of "undergo" with syndrome

Tags: word-usage

Is the sentence.... 
XYZ *(n)* is undergoing ABC syndrome. Right?

Comment: Maybe. What's the context? Give a full sentence and the context.

Comment: If ABC is a syndrome which typically is named as ABC syndrome, then yes?  I think this is too specific of a question, and is lacking all context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you "suffer from" or "show signs of" a syndrome, but you "undergo treatment" for that syndrome. Undergo implies putting up with an action that someone else is performing.

A syndrome is a malady and not normally referred to as the actor like this.

Answer (score 1):

to [*undergo*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/undergo) means  1. to be subjected to; experience. 2. to endure or sustain; suffer; to pass through; experience

One can undergo surgery, suffering, trials, painful procedures, a battery of tests, etc. There is at least the firm hope if not the firm expectation that these things are transitory.

[Syndromes](http://www.medindia.net/patients/patientinfo/syndrome/home.asp) are the group of symptoms that collectively indicate or characterize a disease or disorder. Many syndromes are simply diseases which were characterized by a grouping of symptoms before the cause was known. Often they were names after the person who first described the constellation, so we have Down Syndrome (mental retardation, characteristic facial features, typical crease in hand), Carcinoid Syndrome (Cyanotic flushing Diarrhea Bronchial spasm Edema, ascites),  Irritable Bowel Syndrome (chronic abdominal pain, discomfort, bloating, and alteration of bowel habits in the absence of any detectable organic cause), Lesch-Nyhan syndrome, Ehlers Danlos Syndrome, etc.

These are prolonged, often life long disorders or diseases which we **have**, **not** which we **pass through**

Few English speakers would say, I undergo Irritable Bowel Syndrome, but they might undergo more severe bouts.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted... offset ;)

Answer (score 0):

A syndrome is something you have or you experience.

Undergoing can have the same meaning as experiencing, but I have never heard it used this way.

Usually the one would be said to have a syndrome, maybe to suffer from a syndrome.

> The baby was born with Down syndrome. 
>   This building suffers from sick house syndrome.